# How to create a pop window using pygtk?

Tags: python, linux, pygtk

**Todo:**

```
On button click in main window, open a popup dialog
```

**Framework:**

```
pygtk
```

**Experience:**

Beginner

Comment: I think that English isn't your first language. Either way, use a spell checker. Also, the term is popup dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import gtk

d = gtk.Dialog()
d.add_buttons(gtk.STOCK_YES, 1, gtk.STOCK_NO, 2)

label = gtk.Label('Do you like GTK?')
label.show()
d.vbox.pack_start(label)

answer = d.run()
d.destroy()

print answer
```

[image: gtk dialog example]

Comment: You'll also want to destroy the dialog afterwards with `d.destroy()` otherwise it won't disappear.

Also, when checking the response of the dialog, check against the built in constants (e.g. `gtk.RESPONSE_YES`).